# The type or namespace name 'ServiceController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, reference

I have wrote a Windows Service and I have a admin panel which I can configure this service from a web page. In order to this I am using a database. So basically what I am doing is I change the values from the db and the service reads it and it changes its execution time.. etc.

My problem is in my development server everything works fine. When I install my service and upload the web page to the production server I am getting this error

**The type or namespace name 'ServiceController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

It is giving this error in my web page. I have checked the service it is installed and works fine but when I am trying to go to the configuration page for the service it hrows this exception. In my project i see that I have `using System.ServiceProcess;` is added in the top and when I build my solution this dll reference error doesnt show up. Also in the designer it seems like it is already imported:

`<@ Import Namespace="System.ServiceProcess">;` What might be the problem? Can it be a 32-bit / 64-bit issue? ( I know it doesnt make sense but any help will be appreciated)

```
ServiceController agService = new ServiceController("Buddy Service");
while (agService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{                   
  lblServiceStatus.Text = "Running";
  lblServiceStatus.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
  btnStopService.Enabled = true;
  btnStartService.Enabled = false;
  break;
}
```

It throws the exception on the line

```
ServiceController agService = new ServiceController("Buddy Service");
```

I have made sure that "Buddy Service" is in the Services list and it does.

Comment: Yes I am targeting the same version of my dev machine and production server.

Comment: it is set to 2.0. but in other project similar to mine that doesnt have that issue. i think i am missing something here.

Comment: Can you show the code that is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have the assembly referenced correctly.

Try changing this line:

```
ServiceController agService = new ServiceController("Buddy Service");
```

to this:

```
var agService = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("Buddy Service");
```

If this works, you will probably also need to change this line:

```
while (agService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
```

to this:

```
while (agService.Status == System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
```

Comment: OK thanks that seems to be the solution. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

be sure you added the **System.ServiceProcess** in your references list than the user list:

[image: Example]

Comment: Well, it is a web application, I dont have a references folder, the image you show is in a console application. I have tried to add the dll by right click add reference find the System.ServiceProcess from .Net tab and added it and can not see the dll refence in none of the folder. But when I right click my project and select properties tehe I have references, build, accessibilty. in my references list I can see the System.ServiceProcess in tehre.